# A stochastic process similar to random walk

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

The stochastic process $\{k_t\}$ evolves as follows ($k_0 > 0$ is given):

$$
k_{t+1} = \begin{cases}\frac52k_t, & \text{with prob. }= \frac12 \\
\frac58k_t, & \text{with prob. }= \frac12
\end{cases}
$$

Can we show that $\mathbb{P}(\{k_t\} \text{ has exceeded } 4 \text{ at least once for }k\leq T)$ approaches 1 as $T\to\infty$? Does this has something to do with ergodicity theory? Does the answer in general depend on the probabilities (1/2 and 1/2) and the coefficients (5/2 and 5/8)? Or, is there any theorem that deals with problems of this kind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not difficult to check that $k_n$ has the same law as the process $k_0(\frac{5}{4})^{n}2^{S_n}$, where $S_n$ is a simple symmetric random walk, and from here, you just use the law of large numbers to conclude $k_n \to \infty$ almost surely, which should answer your question.

Alternatively, just note that $\log k_n$ is a right skewed random walk.

Comment: I would have thought $\log k_n$ was the easy approach, so the probabilities $1/2$ and $1/2$ and coefficients $5/2$ and $5/8$ do matter (while the $4$ does not apart from starting with  $0 < k_0<4$) and, since $\frac 12 \log \frac52 +\frac 12 \log \frac58 \ge 0$, you get the result